# Call to undefined relationship [products] on model [App\Category] in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am creating a simple inventory system using larvel 7. I ran in to the problem with

```
Call to undefined relationship [products] on model [App\Category].
```

I am creating a two tables category and products I want have relationship with them.

Category table

```
id categoryname
1   drink
2   biscuits
3   toy
```

product table

```
id productname category
 1   fanta        1
 2   apple juice  1
 3    buildblocks 3
```

I need to category table and product table look like this this and get the data and passing to the table. I need this below output:

```
id productname categoryname
1   fanta          drink
```

While I am running the program I got this error:

```
Call to undefined relationship [products] on model [App\Category].
```

I don't know why it has happing. What I tried so far I attached below.

**Model**

**Category**

```
    class Category extends Model
{
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'categoryname',
    ];


}
```

**Product**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_name',
        'category',
    ];

    public function category (){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category','category','id');
    }
}
```

**view.blade.php**

```
 <tbody>
    @foreach ($products as $key => $product)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$key}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->product_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->category->categoryname}}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@view')->name('product.view');
```

**ProductController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    
    public function view()
    {
    $products = Product::with('category')->get();
    dd($products);
    $categories = Category::with('products')->get();
    return view ('product.view')-> with([
        'products' => $products,
        'categories' => $categories,
    ]);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: `'ProductController::ProductController@view'` => `'ProductController@view'`

Comment: have to changed

Comment: what do i want change?

Comment: Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@view')->name('product.view');

Comment: not i got the error Class 'App\Models\Category' not found

Comment: Please eidt your mode and  add the entire code of your Category model.

Comment: which is a different error now .... did you create a file in `app/Models` named `Category.php` and that has a namespace of `App\Models` declared and the class is named `Category`?  I get the impression you keep looking at stuff for Laravel 8

Comment: i attached the screenshot image of folder structure it is easy to solve the problem

Comment: i done that again got this error Call to undefined relationship [products] on model [App\Category].

Comment: you never defined a relationship on Category for `products`, why would there be one there? are you following some tutorial or something?

Comment: no sir. my friend help me on this project. so how defined defined a relationship on Category for products

Comment: so what to make a relationship pls help us

Answer (score 0):

In your Category Model, you have to add the reverse relationship as well, because you are using it when you want to retrieve the list of the categories.

**Category Model:**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'categoryname',
    ];

    public function products (){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product','category','id');
    }
}
```

The above relationship declaration is important because you are referring to it in this line in your controller:

```
$categories = Category::with('products')->get();
```